# Select all if blah.. else select all where blah

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have an enum like:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(int, name) {
    kAll,
    kFirstType,
    kSecondType
};
```

then I do:

```
if (type == kAll) {
        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = %ld", itemID];
    }
    else {
        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = %ld AND type = %ld", itemID, type];
    }
```

How can I combine this into ONE query like:

```
"SELECT CASE WHEN type = 0 THEN (SELECT ALL ITEMS) ELSE '* WHERE ID = blah AND type = meh' END;
```

How would I do that with a query? I don't want the `if (blah) then query = meh.. else query = other..`

Comment: What's wrong with having two separate queries?

Comment: Nothing. I just want to know how to do it with one. I already have the code doing the above, I would just like to know how it's done with a single query.

Comment: @EvanBashir No - that has nothing to do with the question. - Brandon: You want to move the case distinction into the SQL?

Comment: You don't. You have two separate needs based on code. You either want all types or a specific type. SQL doesn't support what you want.

Comment: @luk2302 Correct. @rmaddy; Ok :(

Comment: I have to go with rmaddy here: it would be pain in the ass to do it with sql, if at all possible. In general you should not move this kind of business logic into sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
select * from myTable where id = :id and (:type = 0 or :type = type)
```

Or this:

```
select * from myTable where id = ? and (? in (0, type))
```

But I wouldn't expect the second one in particular to perform well. I haven't tested either version.

There's no way to change the structure of the `WHERE` clause from within the statement. You'd need some kind of `eval` function, which isn't built-in to SQLite. You can find the source code for a loadable `eval` extension [in the SQLite source tree](http://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact/f971962e92ebb8b0) if you want, but that seems like overkill.